# .htaccess is not redirecting pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i would like to redirect specific page urls and using the following in .htaccess that is not working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule /antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=13 /antalya_apartment.php?bid=4&page=0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /antalya_apartment.php?bid=3&page=113 /antalya_apartment.php?bid=4&page=0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /antalya_apartment.php?bid=5&page=105 /antalya_apartment.php?bid=4&page=0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /antalya_apartment.php?bid=6&page=160 /antalya_apartment.php?bid=4&page=0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /antalya_apartment.php?bid=7&page=87 /antalya_apartment.php?bid=4&page=0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /antalya_apartment.php?bid=8&page=68 /antalya_apartment.php?bid=4&page=0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i would also like to give a 404 to

    RewriteRule /antalya_apartment.php?bid=2&page=13

and then redirect to 

    /antalya_apartment.php?bid=4&page=0

Comment: Make sure that Apache's `mod_rewrite` module is enabled in your server!

Comment: i know mod_rewrite is enabled as this works

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]